# Water Heater Circuit Breaker is being tripped only in the hot summer months

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, water-heater

I've seen plenty of explanations for why a water heater could trip the breaker but for us it is only happening on the hottest days of summer and I haven't found any explanation that, as far as I understand it, would give cause to that.

We do have A/C but it's on a different circuit.  As far as I can tell the water heater is on it's own circuit since after it's tripped, everything else works.  I don't know why we would be seeing it only trip due to heat somehow.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Some breaker trip function is due to heat caused by the current.  Is the breaker in a hotter section of the house, or outside in the sun?  Might also be the breaker is working near it's normal limit and a bit of extra heat pushes it over.

Comment: Common for water heaters is 30 amp breaker with 10 gauge wire(or larger).  Can you confirm.

Comment: How old are the breakers? If @crip659 is right about it thermally tripping because the room is hotter than normal, the breaker may be worn out and tripping earlier (at a lower temperature) than it's intended to. I've seen that happen with some old breakers. Or could be a bad connection making the breaker heat up and trip.

Comment: when the breaker trips, what else is not working ?

Comment: Can you post the nameplate of the water heater, and the size of the breaker? Even better, a photo of the breaker and panel.

Comment: @Ruskes   code requires dedicated circuits for nearly all hard wired WH so it's very unlikely anything else would be out of service.   Point of use WHs that plug into an outlet do not have this requirement.

Comment: maybe your WH is EOL

Comment: Where in/on the house is the panel the water heater breaker's in located at?